# What is the difference between enterpriseId and memberId in an asset model ( queried using marketing cloud REST API)

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

Using the marketing cloud REST API, I am trying to query an asset (say email) and the extract has both enterpriseID as well as memberId. Both of which seem to be the MID [Business Unit] of the Org. What is the difference between them then?. If I want an asset created (using REST API) against a specific Business Unit, what do I to populate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in Enterprise 2 - the enterprise ID is your parent business unit i.e. your enterprise account. The MemberID is the MID of the business unit, which would differ if you are referencing the child BU.

Comment: Thank you @iManage. That makes sense. So, the enterprise ID would always be the same but the memberID would refer to the child BU, from where you would want to extract/create an asset.